# React: CMD File to Run Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I'm attempting to write a .cmd file to install dependencies and then run the React application I've created. After researching I have the code below in a .cmd file:

```
@echo off
npm install
pause
npm run dev
```

Npm install to install dependencies, a pause afterwords, and npm run dev to launch the application. For whatever reason, after `npm install` is ran, the command window closes and doesn't make it to the pause. Running `npm install` in VS code in the same directory receives...

```
PS C:\testApp> npm install
npm WARN @date-io/date-fns@1.3.13 requires a peer of date-fns@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.20.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-each\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 30.79s

147 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the npm.cmd which is actually called and runs the npm command it looks like this:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js" %*
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /b %errorlevel%
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
```

Your problem lies in that last line : `EXIT /b` which exits the current cmd window. I guess you could just copy that script and run it instead of calling the npm directly.

So basically something like this:

```
@ECHO off
REM change the path to your local nodejs
node.exe  "c:\program files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js" install

pause
npm run dev
```